# Using a Session interface in another class

Tags: java, session, tomcat, websocket

I have a web application I am making using a websocket API to handle the websockets, here is the code for that part

```
package comm2.hello;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

import org.apache.catalina.session.*;

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/echo")
public class wschat {
    private static ArrayList<Session> sessionList = new ArrayList<Session>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        try {
            sessionList.add(session);
            // asynchronous communication
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("hello");
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void send(String text, Session session) throws IOException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(text);
    }
}
```

I am trying to have another java class then call into the `send` method to send messages, using the following code.

```
package comms;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.Session;

import comm2.hello.*;
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        wschat h = new wschat();
        String text = "hello";
        //session shouldn't be null but not sure what to make it
        Session session = null;
        h.send(text,session);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I have the `session` variable in the `main.java` class set to `null` which will thus always produce a `null pointer` error. This is because I am not sure what to make `session` equal to, does anyone have any idea what to initialize the `session` variable to in `main.java`?

Comment: Session is an interface not a class object.

Comment: You probably want something that implements Session.

Comment: @brso05 didn't know sorry about that. So I would want my class to probably extend Session if I am thinking about it right or implement it?

Comment: It's alright lol ya if you want to create a Session you could implement it yourself or there is probably already Java implementations out there.  I'm not familiar with WebSockets but when I looked up the Session in package javax.websocket.Session it says its an interface so you can't create an object from it.